# How to display scores for meeting --fail-under requirement .py files in .py lint, while using pre-commit?

Tags: python, pylint, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

My current `pylint` configuration:

1. Installed via `pip` (in requirements.txt).
2. The `.pre-commit-config.yaml`:

```
  - repo: local
    hooks:
        name: pylint
        entry: pylint
        language: system
        types: [ python ]
        files: ^src/
        args:
          [
              "-rn", # display messages
              "--rcfile=.pylintrc",
              "--fail-under=8.5"
          ]
```

3. Execution method:

```
    source venv/bin/activate &&\
    pip freeze &&\
    pre-commit install &&\
    pre-commit run --all-files
```

When all .py files receive score higher than 8.5 then `pylint` is just passing and do not displaying any message. Is there any method to see all of the communicates even if `--fail-under` is met? (so we know what some is wrong with the files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a setting which will force the output to always display: [`verbose: true`](https://pre-commit.com/#config-verbose) but it is **only intended for debug purposes** as it tends to make the output noisy and your contributors will be likely to mentally filter it out as *warning noise*

using your example:

```yaml
  - repo: local
    hooks:
        name: pylint
        entry: pylint
        language: system
        types: [ python ]
        files: ^src/
        args:
          [
              "-rn", # display messages
              "--rcfile=.pylintrc",
              "--fail-under=8.5"
          ]
        verbose: true
```

unrelated, but there's no reason to use `args` for a `repo: local` hook since nothing can override it, you can specify those directly in `entry`:

```
    entry: pylint --rn --rcfile=.pylintrc --fail-under=8.5
```

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit